# Error: "The best overloaded method match for" and "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I got error in "`sqlDR.GetString("SECTION_NAME")`".

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(StringConnection.sqlAddress);
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select SECTION_NAME from SECTION", conn);
            SqlDataReader sqlDR;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sqlDR = comm.ExecuteReader();

                while (sqlDR.Read())
                {
                    string branch = sqlDR.GetString("SECTION_NAME");
                    cmbBranch.Items.Add(branch);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataReader.GetString() via columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228972/datareader-getstring-via-columnname)

Comment: because GetString takes ints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use GetSrting() with a string parameter.
GetString() gets the column index as a parameter.
In your example SECTION_NAME has 0 column index.
So your code must be `sqlDR.GetString(0);`

if your query was select `SOMETHING_ELSE,SECTION_NAME from SECTION"`
your code must be `sqlDR.GetString(1);` to get the value of SECTION_NAME

Answer (score 0):

> sqlDR.GetString("SECTION_NAME") method requires integer as parameter

your parameter is string with the value of **"SECTION_NAME"**.